# Convert bytes to string in python

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, decoding

I have the following printed bytes returned from another system using sockets:

`b"\x0bMessage Received!\r\x1c\r"`

For example:
`print(b"\x0bMessage Received!\r\x1c\r".decode(encoding="utf-8"))`

And a I got

Can you help me to understand how to get an output like this `Message Received!` from that message.

Comment: Try this, `print(b"\x0bMessage Received!\r\x1c\r".replace(b'\x0b', b'').decode(encoding="utf-8"))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to strip out the unwanted characters (in this case vertical tab and carriage return):

```
>>> bs = b"\x0bMessage Received!\r\x1c\r"
>>> print(bs.decode().strip())
Message Received!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
b"\x0bMessage Received!\r\x1c\r".decode("utf-8")
```